# What is the most effective single word to convey the concept of a phrase's meaning being "lost in translation"?

Tags: idioms, translation

Basically I'm wondering if there is a concise way to represent the loss of understanding a foreigner would experience if they were to encounter an American idiom for the first time.

An example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjwofYhUJEM

Comment: You got an answer to get you started, but we're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 1):

As far as the question in the title of your question, I believe the word you are looking for is **idiom**.

> **idiom:** 5.An expression peculiar to or characteristic of a particular language, especially when the meaning is illogical or separate from the meanings of its component words

(from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiom))

And what the foreigner would experience, your word is likely **confusion**.